# How to call mouse events in text field

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, actionview

I want to get focus to the text field on mouseover. How to do this? Now my code lookd like this

```
  <div class='label_input'>
    <%= f.label :username %>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
    <div class='clearfix'></div>
  </div>
```

Expecting similar to the HTML code

```
<input type="text" onmouseover="this.focus()"></input>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass an `onmouseover` to `text_field` ([docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_field)).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I just skip the erb and write the html

You can try:

```
<div class='label_input'>
    <%= f.label :username %>
    <input id="user_name" name="user[name]" size="30" type="text" onmouseover="this.focus()"></input>
    <div class='clearfix'></div>
  </div>
```

I find that in some cases the rails view helpers get more cumbersome than html. So, use what's  most easy.

This way is really helpfull when you update select boxes with javascript.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class='label_input'>
  <%= f.label :username %>
  <%= f.text_field :username, onmouseover: "this.focus()" %>
  <div class='clearfix'></div>
</div>
```